# How to paste a copied string in Web Browser using selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have created a method to copy a text in the text box. Now i want to paste it in the new browser tab search engine(text box). Following is the code

```
public void Method()
    {driver.FindElement(Ad_Search_Direct_Link_Text).SendKeys(Keys.Control + "a");
        driver.FindElement(Ad_Search_Direct_Link_Text).SendKeys(Keys.Control + "c");

        ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("window.open();");

         driver.FindElement(Ad_Search_Direct_Link_Text).SendKeys(Keys.Control + "v");
        driver.FindElement(Ad_Search_Direct_Link_Text).SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
    }
```

I am able to execute my test case upto copy and openeing a new tab. But cannot paste the text i copied from the text box.  Also the test case throws no exception but did not paste the copied text in the tab.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem to me that you are attempting to perform an action when you could be passing a variable. The text located at the element found by driver.FindElement(Ad_Search_Direct_LinkText) should be assigned to a variable and then you can pass the variable into the browser like driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(variable);

Assign the element's value to a variable:

```
public IWebElement MyElement => driver.FindElement(Ad_Search_Direct_Link_Text);
public static string MyString => MyElement.Text;
```

Create Action to use variable:

```
public void RedirectURL(string url)
{
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
}
```

Call method to redirect:

```
RedirectURL(MyString);
```

Comment: Loffin A- I am trying to copy the string in the text box not the element. As your solution is copying the element than the text inside that element

Comment: But thanks a lot for your help, i  tried your code with little modification.   string aa = Ad_Search_Direct_Link_Text.GetAttribute("value").ToString();   This worked now.